# Zurb Foundation website - blank when printing

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I've got this website built with Zurb Foundation 4. Problem is, when I try to print it (on paper, old school) all I get is a blank page. How come? Should I set a specific CSS for printing, and if so how?

- Carl Carlsson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you're using foundation.min.css you should use foundation.css
- And    remove the @media print and all its contents in the
  foundation.css    file

This should fix it partially.

If it still doesnt work I suggest to make a screenshot and paste it in word and print that screenshot.